# Play! 1.2.5 javascript datetimepicker not getting displayed

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

Folks,

I am trying to add a DateTimePicker javascript file in one of the screen. On clicking the calender icon, the calender is not getting poped up.

I added the javascript file in the `public/javascript` folder and the image in the `public/images` folder.

Then I added this line in main.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@{'/public/javascripts/datetimepicker_css.js'}" ></script>
```

and this line for diaplsying the image beside the textbox:

```
<input type="text" styleId="demo1" name="transaction.returnDate" size="10">
<img src="@{'/public/images/cal.gif'}" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

When the screen is loaded, the image is getting diaplsyed properly beside the textbox. But when I click it, the calendar is not getting displayed.

I use these two lines in my other struts application and it works fine:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/MediaTest/datetimepicker/datetimepicker_css.js">

<html:text styleId="demo1" name="returnForm" property="returnDate" size="10"></html:text>
<img src="/MediaTest/datetimepicker/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

Please let me know how to make it work.

Thanks,

Comment: could you please share javascript console logs?

Comment: In Chrome browser, I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: i need full stacktrace. Is the exception thrown by your javascript or the library that you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `styleId` attribute to `id`

```
<input type="text" id="demo1" name="transaction.returnDate" size="10">
```

Comment: ok it starts working now, But with this, came another problem. When I try to get the date value in the controller, it is coming as `null`. Not sure whats going on :( The name of the controller action is: `public static void returnSuccess(TransactionDetails transaction)` and I am trying to print the value in console using: `System.out.println(transaction.returnDate);`. I tried removing the quotes also like this: `<input type="text" id="demo1" name=transaction.returnDate size="10">` but still not working :( Please let me know why is it coming as null in the action controller. Thanks,

Comment: what is the type of `returnDate`? Also another question, what is the value of `returnDate` while form being submitted? There will be a type mismatch with input value and `transaction.returnDate`. For instance if `transaction.returnDate` was `long` and the input value is `12.12.12` then it will not being binded to modal.

Comment: In the `TransactionDetails` model, it is `java.util.Date`. The form is submittted only after selecting a value from the datetimepicker for that field i.e. the value is not null.

Comment: I guess it is a parsing problem. Could you please log `params.get("transaction.returnDate")`. If it is not null, then parse it to Date and simply set your `transaction.returnDate`.

Comment: Ok if I change the type in model from `java.util.Date` to `String` then I am able to get the value printed in the console. But For this, I don't want to change the model type from `Date` to `String`. Do you know about an alternative for resolving this other than changing the model data type?

Comment: Ok this one is logging the date properly: `System.out.println(params.get("transaction.returnDate"));` Shall I do it in this way? OR we can parse it in the template itself? Just concerned about the coding standards else I will get some thrashing from my senior :( Please let me know so that I can close off this thread. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i prefer to do parsing on server side. `Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(params.get("transaction.returnDate"));` will do your work :)